# Do I have to be on Azure server to take full advantage of Intuit Partner Platform?

Tags: .net, sdk, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am an intern analyst at a small software development firm.  Answers to the following questions will help me in gathering requirements for our web service:

We are going to use Amazons server to deploy web service and we want to integrate quickbooks with the service, do I have to bo on Azure server to take full advantage of Intuit Partner Platform for the use of .NET interfaces?

After some research, it seems that the Quickbooks SDK is going to be obsolete...Is there any truth to this?

Is everyone leaning to Frontrunner and IPP?

I hope these questions are accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I have to bo on Azure server to take full advantage of Intuit
>   Partner Platform for the use of .NET interfaces?

No, definitely not.

IPP is a REST XML (and soon JSON too) based interface. It's not tied to ANY programming language or platform. You can access it just fine with .NET from any server, and you can access it with any other programming language (there are libraries out there for other languages too: [PHP QuickBooks DevKit](http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/), [Java QuicKBooks DevKit](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_IPP_Java_DevKit), etc.)

> After some research, it seems that the Quickbooks SDK is going to be obsolete...Is there any truth to this?

For *QuickBooks for WINDOWS*, Intuit has continually re-affirmed their position that the SDK is not going anywhere. Read their blog posts: http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2012/10/the-quickbooks-sdk.html  They just recently released a new feature of the SDK, and it has placeholders in it for features that will be in the *next* version of the SDK as well.

The QuickBooks SDK for *QuickBook ONLINE* is likely going to be obsolete. If you're a SaaS app, IPP is the way to go for *QuickBooks ONLINE*.

It's also important to realize that right now, the Intuit Partner Platform *depends on* the SDK for functionality. The way Sync Manager works for Intuit Partner Platform apps is that it actually opens a normal SDK connection to QuickBooks for Windows, and sends QuickBooks normal, SDK, qbXML requests to create/update data in QuickBooks, and also for various other things like voids, deletes, etc.

*That means that even if Intuit WANTED to abandon the SDK, they can't right now. Not without a HUGE re-write of the Intuit Partner Platform on their side.*

> Is everyone leaning to Frontrunner and IPP?

Ugh, no.

A large number of apps on AppCenter right now are NOT .NET apps at all. I know we've helped build and publish at least 10 or so PHP apps, and we've talked to many other people using Ruby, Python, or Java.

Additionally, it's important to understand that right now IPP isn't suitable for everyone.

- You have to be a SaaS app to use it (that means that if you're NOT a SaaS app, you *have* to use the SDK right now)
- QuickBooks for WINDOWS for Intuit Partner Platform *is terrible* right now (the interface is buggy, unreliable, incomplete, and just a general mess)
- Intuit is in the middle of a big data services re-write (they are actually about 6 months behind on v3 development - if you develop for IPP now, plan on re-writing huge chunks of your app in 6 months when v3 is usable)

Comment: Through my research I have learned in the past it has been difficult to integrate c# and QuickBooks but has been increasingly easier...Am I inaccurate?

Comment: It's no more difficult than integrating in any other language. QuickBooks as a whole has a sort of weird API (COM-based) that isn't really client-server like most people expect it to be. That, along with the obscure error messages that QuickBooks throws, and the fact that a lot of developer aren't at all familiar with the software itself before having to integrate with it, trips a lot of people up.  For simple tasks that most people need like adding customers/invoices/payments to QuickBooks, it's pretty easy to integrate with once you get going.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the QuickBooks SDK has been deprecated. Although the SDK support team is still making sincere efforts to keep things going, there have been breaking changes to the SDK in recent QuickBooks releases (for example, Enhanced Inventory Receiving) and the latest revision (12) has not been fully implemented.

The Frontrunner program is just a vehicle for getting technicial assistance and marketing help. There's no requirement that you use Frontrunner or Azure in order to interface with IPP.

The most important thing you should be aware of right now are big changes that were announced for version 3 of IPP. You are perhaps already following this topic, but if you're not I would advise you to look into it.

Comment: Thank you Paul. You actually have indirectly answered a question for me through someone else previously regarding .NET interfaces and QuickBooks. May I ask you some further questions about this subject until I get the hang of this?

Comment: Paul is incorrect. The SDK has NOT been deprecated. Read this article by Intuit in October, 2012: http://ippblog.intuit.com/blog/2012/10/the-quickbooks-sdk.html  Intuit specifically says: *We currently have no plans to retire the SDK.*

Comment: I agree that the SDK has not been officially deprecated by Intuit, and I also give mad props to the small group within Intuit that still actively supports the SDK. Can we agree on a word that accurate captures the institutional commitment to the SDK at Intuit? My view is "deprecated" nails it even if it doesn't jibe with official pronouncements.

Comment: Agreed on all counts! The truth is I use and depend on the SDK every day and I can't say the same of the IPP. "I would choose to avoid IPP before I chose to avoid the SDK" - very well put. Keith, you are a great asset to the Intuit developer community and Intuit doesn't deserve you!

Comment: After further research, the majority of blogs ive read are denouncing QB SDK...You both are awesome...how do I reach you for chat?

Comment: Intuit App Store shows all IPP apps first, then SDK apps, this show that Intuit is favoring IPP, I do not agree with this, they are being heavily influenced by Microsoft because Micro has a hand in Intuits pocket\